# Extracting an object from a nested list of objects

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-3

I have a problem that I have created a smaller version of.

I have a list of objects of type `A` lets call that `L`

```
L = List[A]
```

In `A` there is another list of objects `B` which have a property `X`.

To collect all `A` that have a `B` with `X` equaling `V`

```
L.filter(x => x.B.exists(y => y.X == V)).map(a => a.B)
```

Example code from REPL

```
class B(val X:Int){
  override def toString =
    s"b:$X"
}

class A(val b: List[B]) {
  override def toString =
    s"a: $b"
}

val listA1 = List(new B(1), new B(2), new B(3))
val listA2 = List(new B(1), new B(7), new B(12))
val listA3 = List(new B(9), new B(5), new B(3))

val L = List(new A(listA1), new A(listA2), new A(listA3))

println(L) // List(a: List(b:1, b:2, b:3), a: List(b:1, b:7, b:12), a: List(b:9, b:5, b:3))

val res = L.filter(x => x.b.exists(y => y.X == 3)).map(a => a.b)

println(res) // List(List(b:1, b:2, b:3), List(b:9, b:5, b:3))
```

Now the problem - How to get a list of the `B` objects whose `X` value is `3`?

That is a list as follows

```
List(b:3, b:3)
```

In the real world I am after other attributes of `B` but first I need to get the `B`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your request, this is all you need.

```
L.flatMap(_.b.filter(_.X == 3))
```

BTW, your use upper/lower-case variable names is inconsistent, haphazard, and rather confusing.